# Angular 9 - Redirect to same URL and REFRESH page, but should call only current page API call

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router, angular9

Want to redirect to same URL, also want to refresh page , I have tried using anchor tag with href, but it will refresh the page and call all api from starting of application. in angularjs we use state.go in which the whole page is not get refresh. 
eg. :
http://localhost:4200/user/27b3bcd3-5de9-4ca6-b2c9-d8ad708518fd/details/main 
if this is the page and this details page contain button, on click on button another user details should get open, http://localhost:4200/user/985b97cd-fad4-4194-abd5-adbd9bfa056b/details/main

in angualr 9 have tried routerLink ,and Router.navigate, but only id is updated in url but page is not refresh.

Comment: Page will not refresh, it's by the design. That's why we call it a single page application. Could you please explain more about the problem?

Comment: you can use: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})] })`\

Comment: I know, but I want to update current page data with new data, which is not updated

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I tried your solution but it won't work, only id in url is updated

Comment: I only want to update current parent component, so that all child component data is get update, but i don't want to refresh whole page from route, currently when I redirect to same url my whole application get refresh

Answer (score 1):

If you need a real page reload then you need to use `document.location.reload();` instead of router.

Answer (score 1):

This worked from me in a similar scenario. Route to the required page and reload.

```
  this.router.navigate(['/'])
       .then(() => {
           window.location.reload();
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `window.location.reload();` within a function which is fired on button click. This will refresh the current nav url.

Comment: what a reason to repeat an existing answer?

Comment: Hi satanTime , apology as the answer looks similar but it actually using root object `window` for invoking reload.

Comment: there's no `WINDOW` injection token in angular, only `DOCUMENT` if you want to support SSR, and FYI `window.location === document.location` is true.